# Trouble with gesture recognizers in subviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'm having a rather basic problem, I've looked around (here, google, etc) and haven't found a solution for this:

In my View Controller's `viewDidLoad`, I have this:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myfunc:)];

//I have a UIScrollView named "containerView"
//here's some code that creates an UIView in a variable named "myView"

//this works fine, I can see "myView" when I run it
[containerView addSubview:myView];

[myView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

and then I have this function in the same class:

```
- (void)myfunc:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
    NSLog(@"hola!"); //never runs
}
```

The call to `NSLog` never runs. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Some extra info: it seems no touch events are ever sent to the subview. However, I tried adding an UIView with a button inside, all in the UIScrollView, and the button receives the touch event just fine, so the problem is only with programmatically added subviews.

Comment: Have you tried long pressing the screen?

Comment: Well that's the whole point of all this, ain't it..

Comment: I think so :) just trolling around ^^ Your code looks perfectly, anyway.

Comment: Maybe you could 1. add the recognizer before you add YourView as a subview; 2. inserting it specifically on the top of any other views so no other view can intercept its touch events.

Comment: I tried #1, no luck. But, I tried adding a Round Rect Button inside the view and it doesn't seem to be responding to touch... any idea why this would happen?

Comment: yes, exactly what I thought. Try #2.

Comment: well, they are already on top, it's just that UIScrollView and a bunch of calls to `addSubview` in different positions so they don't even overlap. So, they _are_ on the very top, right? Any change the scroll view thing is messing with me?

Comment: Yeah, UIScrollView *badly* intercepts touch events.

Comment: There _must_ be a way of receiving touch events in subviews of a UIScrollView :| :| :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strangely enough, adding a "container" UIView inside the UIScrollView, and then the other subviews inside this container, made it work. Now touch events are sent to the subviews.

Answer (score 0):

[How can a superview interecept a touch sequence before any of its subviews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673903/how-can-a-superview-interecept-a-touch-sequence-before-any-of-its-subviews)

TLDR:

```
[containerView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
```

do it just as you add the gesture recogniser to the scroll view.

also look into

```
[containerView setDelaysContentTouches:NO];
```

If the above behaviour isn't quite right.

for more info:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Comment: I played with those properties, they didn't help. Look at my edit on the question, I added a subview manually on the interface editor, and it receives touch events, but not my programmatically added subviews...

Answer (score 0):

I think on myFunc you must do somethings like that:

```
switch (reconiger.state)
{
    case UIGestureRecognizerBegin:
      //Do something when start recognizer
      break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerEnd:
      //Do something when end recognizer
      break;
}
```