# UITapGestureRecognizer on UILabels in subview of UIScrollView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

I have a problem where my UITapGestureRecognizer on my UILabels in a content view in my UIScrollView is not calling it's methods.

The view hierarchy is as follows:

- scrollView (UIScrollView)

  - contentView (UIView)

    - testLabel (UILabel) - here is where the UITapGestureRecognizer is attached

I have distilled the code down to an example to highlight the problem

```
// Set scrollview size - Added in Storyboad
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([arrayOfVerbs count]*self.view.frame.size.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)];
[scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:YES]; // Tried both yes and no
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

// Add content view
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)];
[scrollView addSubview:contentView];

// Add test UILabel
UILabel *testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
[testLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[testLabel setText:@"Test touch"];
[testLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[contentView addSubview:testLabel];

// Add gesture recogniser
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(playSound:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[testLabel addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

And this is the method that the tap gesture recogniser should call

```
- (void)playSound:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    NSLog(@"play sound");

    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        int pronounNumber = [sender.view tag];
        int exampleNumber = (int)sender.view.frame.origin.x%(int)self.view.frame.size.width;

        NSLog(@"Pronoun is %i and example is %i", pronounNumber, exampleNumber);
    }
}
```

This method is never called when I tried to touch on the UILabel.

I have tried setting the property canCancelContentTouches to both YES and NO on the scroll view as suggested by this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286938/trouble-with-gesture-recognizers-in-subviews), but it's still not working.

The strange thing is, if I add a UILabel outside of the scrollView, then the gesture recogniser works! So the problem only occurs in my contentView which is a subview of my scrollView.

I am using auto-layout, if that might be any difference?

Thanks!

Comment: Try setting [contentView setClipBounds:YES]; and see whether your `Label` inside the `ContentView` is visible, if not then your `Label` is not in touching area, adjust your resizing properties..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The scroll view also has a gesture recogniser. By default, only 1 gesture recognizer can be handling touches at any one time. You need to make yourself the delegate of your gesture and then implement `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` to return `YES`. This will allow it to work at the same time as the scroll view.

Comment: OK, so I set `singleTap.delegate = self;` and implemented `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in my .h file, and add `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is the delegate method being called? What is the size of the content view (log it)?

Comment: OMG! You got it! it was `contentView size <UIView: 0xc0345b0; frame = (0 0; 640 0)`, so it had zero hight!! Thank you soo soo zoo much!!!

Comment: Strangely enough, @wain, it DOES seem to work (these days anyway) if you add a tap (UITapGestureRecognizer) to "cells" of a stack view inside a scrollview.  Without using shouldRecognizeSimultaneously.  I don't know why.

Comment: For anyone reading this I had a fascinating obscure problem.  I was generating UIViewControllers and their views on the fly, and inserting them in a scroll view.  Of course, view controllers - per se - are not particularly retained when you create them!  the view remains but the VC is gone, unless you keep it.

Answer (score 2):

Add delegate to tagGestures,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(playSound:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.delegate = self;
[testLabel addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

EDIT:-

```
contentView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

put this line your code it'l work.

Comment: Hi, I just tried setting the delegate to self, and implemented `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` protocol and - `(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch` method. Still doesn't work, also why would I need to implement a delegate for it when I don't need it for UILabels outside of the scrollview?

Comment: @Joseph Williamson:have you added last line of code in my answer?once add it and check.

Comment: once check your scrollView view frame.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by checking my scrollview view frame?

Comment: @Joseph Williamson:Problem is either with contentView frame or scrollview frame once give static values and check.

Answer (score -3):

```
[yourlabel.addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureDeFromage];
```

should add the gesture explicitly to your labels.